# rosserial arduino use PROGMEM in ros_lib

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

as stated here (http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Tutorial/Memory) adruinos usually do not have much SRAM and it is easy to use it all up by using many constant strings

> Notice that there's not much SRAM
> available in the Uno. It's easy to use
> it all up by having lots of strings in
> your program.

<sarcasm warning> The nice feature of the arduino IDE in this cases is that it does not fail to compile or upload but only the arduino programm will run 'strangely' </sarcasm warning>

> If you run out of SRAM, your program
> may fail in unexpected ways; it will
> appear to upload successfully, but not
> run, or run strangely. To check if
> this is happening, you can try
> commenting out or shortening the
> strings or other data structures in
> your sketch (without changing the
> code). If it then runs successfully,
> you're probably running out of SRAM.

I have observed this behaviour with my arduino code that uses ros_lib. One of the causes is that ros_lib stores for each topic (publish/subscribe) 3 strings ( md5sum, message type name and topic name ). Particularly if I use topics with namespaces if have observed the problem on arduino uno after setting up only 3 or 4 topics.

How the question: Has anyone considered modifying the message generator for Ardunio such that it uses PROGMEM for storing md5sum, topic and stuff? (Or is it even possible?)

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM

The data is static and I think this would significantly reduce the SRAM usage....

Thank you!

Edit 22.09.: anyone?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193202/rosserial-arduino-use-progmem-in-ros_lib/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-24**:
You might want to try and just report this as an issue over at the [ros-drivers/rosserial](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial) github repo. Do refer to this post in your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I forked from rosserial and created a REPO that supports PROGMEN  usage for the ros relevant constant strings on arduino. There is a pending pull request.

Until then, anybody interested in this can clone into my fork:
https://github.com/strothmw/rosserial

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1